# Interaction between Windows Application Experience and Windows Defender leading to 100% disk active time

Tags: windows, windows-defender, disk-activity

This has been driving me up the wall for some time, but I think I may have finally caught (one of) the instigator(s) in the act.

Solutions already tried with no effect:

- I have run [chkdsk](https://superuser.com/a/470591)
- I do not have    [KB2976978](https://superuser.com/a/891516) installed
- I have    [disabled    superfetch](https://superuser.com/questions/759152/windows-8-1-update-1-disk-usage-100)
- Upgrading to Windows 8.1
- Upgrading to Windows 10

Occasionally my Windows desktop (previously 8, then 8.1, now running 10) would suffer bouts of near unusability. Investigation would lead to Windows Defender `MsMpEng.exe` being reported as the cause of 100% disk active time in Resource Monitor. Presumably this resulted in an extremely unresponsive system because the system had to compete for I/O to read the page file. Looking at the disk activity details in Resource Monitor I see `MsMpEng.exe` reading what looked like every file on the system over the course of 5-10 minutes. There was no scan running in Defender that would explain such behavior. Disabling active protection stops the reads, but doing so isn't a viable solution in my mind.

Operating under the assumption that Defender must be responding to apparent changes in the file system (since the active protection feature presumably reads every file as its created or edited) I've been running SysInternals Process Monitor during these slowdowns to see if I could catch whatever was triggering Defender, and I think I got lucky this time.

[image: A clue! A Clue!]

This is a subset of events captured by process monitor during a run where I also saw the Autodesk directory in the disk activity section of Resource Monitor. We see that `rundll32.exe` is calling `CreateFile` on an existing file, and then Defender comes in and reads the same file (into the page file no less if my understanding of `CreateFileMapping` is correct). Inspecting the stack for the `rundll32.exe`'s call to `CreateFile` we see the following

[image: Stack Trace]

`invagent.dll`/`aeinv.dll` appear to be the root cause here, but what I could find about disabling them was to uninstall KB2976978, which my system does not have.

What's my next step to try to fix this?

Comment: [You might try using the command line to see if the kb is installed](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/04/17/how-to-remove-windows-10-upgrade-updates-in-windows-7-and-8/)

Comment: i would suspect you could , get into the task scheduler taskschd.msc /s and disable 2 things carefully and have some of the insanity stopped.  The occasion for some of this is probably when the system is deemed idle, the updater ran out of the scheduler. Using the "autoruns" program instead might be a easier way to disable scheduled tasks , and save changes to compare to, re-enableing and testing easily. Disabling in task scehduler does not require a re-boot (unlike messing with the registry) , and it can be turned off and on or even time/delay adjusted to suit the user.

Comment: Defender sucks, so use a different Av suite which is not that extremely slow.

Comment: @Moab I have double-checked for that hotfix using your suggestion and reconfirmed that that KB is not installed in my system.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The same problem occurs with any other AV that scans files when CreateFile is called, which so far is any that provides an active protection of some kind.

Comment: I don't have it with NOD32.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Most people don't have the problem I have, Defender or not, so your not seeing the problem with your configuration is not very useful unless you've fixed _this specific problem_ by changing to NOD32.

Comment: capture a xperf trace of the disk IO: http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60 and share it