# rundll32 generates excessive disk I/O when idle

Tags: windows-10

Recently I found that when my computer is idle for a while, `rundll32.exe` runs the following command and generates excessive I/O.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe invagent,RunUpdate -noappraiser eNpRGCNfm0eU4886.4
```

After searching the web, I found one post on this site, [rundll32.exe invagent.dll eating 100% CPU](https://superuser.com/questions/891166/rundll32-exe-invagent-dll-eating-100-cpu)

My problem is slightly different from the one described in that post. Instead of high CPU usage, mine is reading the disk excessively. Windows Performance monitor shows that `rundll32.exe` is scanning through every single file in the system folder (i.e. C:\Windows) and the program files folder.

I tried the solution mentioned in that post. My Customer Experience Improvement Program Settings is already turned off. There is no Windows Update `KB2976978` found in the installed updates list.

I have also searched the Task Scheduler, I have disabled related tasks such as Application Experience. However, this problem is not solved.

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invagent` is part of the Application Experience service and may be an attempt to silently prepare your computer for an upgrade to Windows 10.

The problem may disappear if you remove these updates:

> KB2990214
>
> KB2952664
>
> KB3022345
>
> KB3021917
>
> KB3035583

Use `wusa /uninstall /kb:[number of KB]` on an administrator prompt to remove them in bulk.

([source](https://windowsforum.com/threads/how-to-disable-get-rid-of-application-experience-ceip.209704/))

Answer (score -1):

I just came accross this in a Windows 8 installation.

Although you said you disabled Application Experience entries, I believe it's best to have Task Scheduler kill just ProgramDataUpdater after it runs for 1 minute. That solved my issue.

Steps found in "Most Helpful Reply" by Splitty here:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/windows-host-process-rundll32exe-high-cpu-usage/e0cadea3-0fc8-4330-bdc2-b74b5f685b20

Comment: This question has an answer that has already been accepted, which means the asker tried the solution provided and it worked for them. Please refrain from adding answers unless you are certain that your answer is a better answer than the one already accepted, which is not the case here.